# ZK - Adding component to Treeitem depending on model content

Tags: java, zk

So, I want to add a specific component (either Checkbox or Textbox) depending on the AttType field of my current node. My zul file looks like this:

```
<tree id="permissionTree" width="100%"
        model="@bind(vm.treeModel)" style="text-align:left;">
        <treecols>
            <treecol label="Item" width="400px" />
            <treecol label="Wert" />
        </treecols>
        <template name="model" var="node">
            <treeitem>
                <treerow>
                    <treecell label="@load(node.data.name)" />

                    <treecell> HERE COMPONENT DEPENDING ON node.data.AttType </treecell>
                </treerow>
            </treeitem>
        </template>
    </tree>
```

How can I accomplish this? Oh and I want the Textbox/Checkbox value to be bound to my model as a String, that would be pretty nice.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Edit: I made a little "workaround" for myself. Since I have only 3 possible input types, I just defined them hard-coded:

```
<tree id="permissionTree" width="100%"
        model="@bind(vm.treeModel)" style="text-align:left;">
        <treecols>
            <treecol label="Item" />
            <treecol label="Wert" />
        </treecols>
        <template name="model" var="node">
            <treeitem open="@bind(node.open)" onClick="@command('expandNode', item=node)">
                <treerow>
                    <treecell label="@load(node.data.name)" />
                    <treecell>
                        <textbox visible="@load(node.data.isTextbox)" value="@bind(node.data.value)" />
                        <textbox visible="@load(node.data.isTextarea)" rows="6" width="300px" value="@bind(node.data.value)" />
                        <checkbox visible="@load(node.data.isCheckbox)" checked="@bind(node.data.checkboxValue)" />
                    </treecell>
                </treerow>
            </treeitem>
        </template>
    </tree>
```

And in the constructor of a TreeNode I set the isTextbox/isTextarea/isCheckbox values according to the type. This way the model binding still works :)

Answer (score 0):

As you asked in your previous question: use treeitem renderer and add items you need there. I don't think binding will work for new components.